# Move smaller items to fit empty spaces after reLayout in jQuery isotope

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I would like to move smaller items to empty spaces, after changing size of other item.

This is how it looks on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FRH8v/

For example when you click on no. 2, you will get two empty spaces above it. How to move smaller items to fill those spaces?

Here is code (same like on jsfiddle):

```
$(function(){
    // Modified Isotope methods for gutters in masonry
    $.Isotope.prototype._getMasonryGutterColumns = function() {
        var gutter = this.options.masonry && this.options.masonry.gutterWidth || 0;
        containerWidth = this.element.width();

        this.masonry.columnWidth = this.options.masonry && this.options.masonry.columnWidth ||
        // Or use the size of the first item
        this.$filteredAtoms.outerWidth(true) ||
        // If there's no items, use size of container
        containerWidth;

        this.masonry.columnWidth += gutter;

        this.masonry.cols = Math.floor((containerWidth + gutter) / this.masonry.columnWidth);
        this.masonry.cols = Math.max(this.masonry.cols, 1);
    };

    $.Isotope.prototype._masonryReset = function() {
        // Layout-specific props
        this.masonry = {};
        // FIXME shouldn't have to call this again
        this._getMasonryGutterColumns();
        var i = this.masonry.cols;
        this.masonry.colYs = [];
        while (i--) {
            this.masonry.colYs.push(0);
        }
    };

    $.Isotope.prototype._masonryResizeChanged = function() {
        var prevSegments = this.masonry.cols;
        // Update cols/rows
        this._getMasonryGutterColumns();
        // Return if updated cols/rows is not equal to previous
        return (this.masonry.cols !== prevSegments);
    };

    var $container = $('#container'),
        $element = '.element';

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: $element,
        resizable: false,
        transformsEnabled: true,
        animationEngine: 'best-available',
        layout: 'masonry',
        masonry: {
            gutterWidth: 4,
            columnWidth: 157
        }
    });

    // click action
    $container.find($element).each(function(){
        var that = $(this);

        that.click(function(){
            if( that.hasClass('active') ){
                $container.find($element).removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $container.find($element).removeClass('active');
                that.addClass('active');
            }

            $container.isotope('reLayout');

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's how isotope / masonry works.

I doesn't really remove all "holes" as good as possible. From my experience, I would say that isotope/masonry only pushes tiles up, but doesn't jump over tiles.

In your fiddle, when enlarging "5", "7" won't go up, because it would have to "jump over" 5.

But why? I don't know exactly, but I could imagine 2 reasons:

- It preserves the order of elements. In extreme case, an optimal algorithm could totally shuffle your items. When you would resize individual boxes, you would have completely unpredictable "jumping around" of block during the resize.
- It reduces the computational complexity - more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Computational_complexity

That said, it seems like packery (http://packery.metafizzy.co/) does exactly what you want :)